# How to change the default page in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to change the default page in ASP.NET Core. Instead of `home/index`, I want to return the `Index` view from the `GameController` with this default route:

```
GuessingGame/{controller=Game}/{action=Index}/{id?}
```

[image]

I changed my launch setting this way.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9149/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchUrl": "GuessingGame",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/GuessingGame/Game",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "assignment1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/GuessingGame/Game",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And added these lines of code in the start-up class:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "GuessingGame", pattern: "GuessingGame/{controller=Game}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Doctor", pattern: "{controller=Doctor}/{action=CheckFever}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

But unfortunately, it still returns the `Index` view from the `DoctorController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your default route on `UseEndpoints` following [this naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#crd)

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    //the default route
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "GuessingGame/{controller=Game}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 
    //other routes
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "GuessingGame", pattern: "GuessingGame/{controller=Game}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Doctor", pattern: "{controller=Doctor}/{action=CheckFever}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Home", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: it dose't matter,it runs CheckFever action in doctor controller .don't know why!

Comment: Hmm with your current setup, that is a only problem I can foresee. A little bit strange that it's triggering Doctor controller instead of Home @amirkian

Answer (score 1):

It was so weird that take me two hours to handle it.
I remove .vs folder  becuase I got the 'HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications ' erro and rebuild my project and just added '"launchUrl": "GuessingGame",'in launchsetting.json .
Now it works fine.

Comment: It's **launch**settings - not "lunch"settings......

Answer (score 0):

Remove `GuessingGame/` before `{controller=Game}...`

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "GuessingGame", pattern: "{controller=Game}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: I need this route in uri :GuessingGame/game

Comment: @amirkian are you used ```Area``` in your project?

Comment: There is no Area